# Problems when importing excel file in R

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to upload [this](https://github.com/Projecte-Orbita/sociogrames/blob/master/sociograma.xlsx) file to R (sorry to direct you elsewhere; I don't know how to upload files directly here), but I'm getting the weirdest behaviour.

If, for example, I use readxl package to load:

`temp <- readxl::read_excel("excels/sociograma.xlsx", sheet = 1, col_names = T)`

First, when debugging in R pluggin for pycharm, I already see that something is wrong:
[image]

Thinking it might be the package, I tried with xlsx:

`temp <- read.xlsx("excels/sociograma.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)`

And now the odd part starts; what I get is:

[image]

So, as you can see, some columns are fixed, but others aren't...

Furthermore, if I View() the object in either pycharm or Studio viewers, I find no problem, but still, if I try to operate with the conflicting rows, for instance `temp[, 1]` I get:

`Error:attempt to apply non-function`

My R session info details are:
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
LC_COLLATE=Catalan_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Catalan_Spain.1252    LC_MONETARY=Catalan_Spain.1252
LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Catalan_Spain.1252

Plus a bunch of the usual packages, in particular `readxl_1.3.1`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried `openxlsx::read.xlsx` with no problem.

Comment: Are you on a Windows? I get the same as with read_excel...

Comment: I'm able to use readxl::read_xlsx and readxl::read_excel with no issues. :/

Comment: I tried it on Mac OS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with encodings; so it someone could reproduce it in a Windows I would appreciate it.